# How to find the number of hits on an API in apigateway aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I am facing difficulty in locating the statistics of an API (possibly through a usage plan)

I only found out one aws-cli cmd that provides all the output in one go -

```
  aws apigateway get-usage-plan --usage-plan-id <id>
```

Is there any other way and am I correct in locating the no. of hits for an API.

I also wish to know which is the exact parameter that defines the no. of hits for an API.

### Update

I ran the command and I don't see any concrete output. Here are the screenshots:

[image: json file]

[image: command prompt]

Answer (score 1):

This will be available via CloudWatch metrics. The [metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-metrics-and-dimensions.html) you're specifically looking for is `Count`.

You can access these from the console or CLI.

From the console access the CloudWatch Service, select Metrics and then select `ApiGateway`.

For the CLI you can use the [get-metric-data](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-data.html) function to get the data in a JSON response.

An example of this command is below

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-data --metric-data-queries file://metricdata.json --start-time 2020-06-01T00:00:00Z --end-time 2020-07-01T00:00:00Z
```

With the contents of `metricdata.json` looking similar to the below.

```
[
  {
    "Id": "IdName",
    "MetricStat": {
      "Metric": {
        "Namespace": "AWS/ApiGateway",
        "MetricName": "Count",
        "Dimensions": [
          {
            "Name": "ApiName",
            "Value": "MyApi"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Period": 3600,
      "Stat": "Average",
      "Unit": "Count"
    },
    "Label": "LabelName",
    "ReturnData": true
  }
]
```

By default the count will be aggregated by API, but you can add enhanced monitoring to allow you dig down into individual verbs such as (POST /booking or GET /search).

More information on using CloudWatch with API Gateway is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/monitoring-cloudwatch.html).

Comment: No problem @Techdive, let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Hi chris, I have run the command and getting an error , can you please check the update in the query.

Comment: This appears to be a warning as you're using the --no-verify-ssl option which is considered for allowing insecure SSLs, you should be able to remove this :)

Comment: Hi Chris, actually this is R&D account. So we run it with --no-verify-ssl. Could you please suggest an alternate way. Thanks

Comment: This flag shouldn't need to be use as the AWS service should have a valid SSL certificate. Otherwise you'll always get the warning. Remember this is for the SSL of the host you're connecting to :)

Comment: Actually we have been using this as a default command for aws cli interface while rnd and testing. And it works. Is there any other way ?

Comment: No, this warning is coming from having that flag I am afraid. The command is working its just a warning you'll get :)

Comment: Can you help me figure out with any other command for finding stats

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218224/discussion-between-chris-williams-and-techdive).